# Lumia 520 doesn't ring or shows any sign of incoming call or message when locked

Tags: 8.1, lumia-520, sms, calls

When My Lumia is locked (I mean when it generally asks for Password), it doesn't respond to calls or messages. When I unlock the phone it does alert me on incoming calls and can see all the calls, messages I have missed.

It works fine when connected to my hands free device with Bluetooth and when I use headset to listen to music.

Comment: Which Windows version are you running and have you checked that the latest updates are installed?

Comment: Windows 8.1 I don't think it updates any more

Comment: You should still check that the latest update of 8.1 has been properly installed on your phone. Start with checking that your phone is able to perform backups properly (e.g. by manually telling it to do one).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using latest version  of windows phone 8.1 thats officially,
**LUMIA DENIM - 8.10.14219.341**. as per [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/mobile/support/product/lumia-520/softwareupdate/).

If you are not getting to know about incoming calls or messages,
try resetting your phone in ***Settings > about > reset***,

and if you have tried resetting and still facing issue,
you can get notification in **Notification Center** about phone and messages,

[image: notification center]

or you can add icons in **Quick Status** like,

[image]

> Source :

- [Lumia 520 Latest Version - Microsoft Website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/mobile/support/product/lumia-520/softwareupdate/)
- [notifications + actions - Microsoft Website](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-IN/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/use-quick-actions-on-my-phone)
- [Quick Status - Microsoft Website](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/personalize-my-lock-screen)